# Cash Register Program - C

Tags: c

Good day! In a program I am writing for school we must make a cash register type program, seems simple enough, but for the life of me I can not get it to work. After taking in the number of products bought, then the price of all, the program must ask for the cash to pay, then give back the change. BUT the change must be given in amount of loonies back (or $1 bills), and then just the remaining cents. Help? I've gotten the loonies to work (somewhat) but I don't know how to do the change back.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int itemNum, justChange;
    double prodPrice, tax, cashGiven, change, purchasePrice, changeGiven, changeBack, cashBack;
    float totalPrice;

    //Num of items
    printf ("Number of items: ");
    scanf("%d", &itemNum);

    //Price of items
    printf("Please enter price of items: ");
    scanf("%lf", &prodPrice);

    //Math Stuff
    purchasePrice = itemNum*prodPrice;
    tax = purchasePrice * 0.13;
    totalPrice = purchasePrice*1.13;

    //find change alone
    //justChange = totalPrice


    //Price Output
    printf("Purchase price is: %.2lf \n",purchasePrice );
    printf("TAX (HST 13%):     %.2lf\n",tax );
    printf("Total price is:    %.2lf \n",totalPrice );



    printf("Please Enter Cash: ");
    scanf("%lf", &cashGiven);

    printf("Please Enter Change: ");
    scanf("%lf", &changeGiven);

    //MAth stuuff again

    double endCash;
    double loony;
    int yoloswag;
    endCash = cashGiven - totalPrice;
    loony = endCash/1;
    loony = loony--;

    if (loony<0)
        printf ("Loonies: 0");
    else
    printf("Loonies: %.0lf \n",loony );

    printf("change: %d ", totalPrice-floor(totalPrice) );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For some specific input, what is the *expected* output and what is the *actual* output?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg input cash to pay, then output change back in one line saying amount of 1's to give back and in the next, the remaining cents change. I'm not getting wrong output, I'm just not sure how to show the remaining change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an array with possible change values;

```
double cashValues[6] = {1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01};
```

Then create a for loop in which you try to subtract the possible change values from the difference until the difference is zero.

```
double difference;
difference = cashGiven - totalPrice;
while (difference != 0) {
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {
         if(cashValues[i] <= difference) {
              difference -= cashValues[i];
              printf("%f \n", cashValues[i]);
              i=0;
         }
    }
}
```